# How to convert frame number to time or vice versa in MATLAB VideoReader

Tags: matlab, video, frame-rate

I have a video captured by a webcam which captures the video with variable framerate. While I am reading it with the VideoReader and read(video,frame_num) functions, I am reading each frame and showing it into gui inside a while loop by converting the time value to frame. But it is not correct to get the either value by multiplying or dividing with the framenumber since it is not constant.

Let say matlab says, video has 3000 frames and 15fps then it should be 200secs long but actual length is much longer than this while it uses less frame where the image is still.

How to get the frame number or time value from other. I am iterating over time, thus I need to get correct number.

Isn't there any chance to get frame number vs time value vector or struct whatever.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: More information about your video container is needed. Are you reading the data straight into MATLAB or is there an intermediate step? What version of MATLAB are you using? @horchler might have some insight based on his experience with his [`QTWriter`](https://github.com/horchler/QTWriter) class.

Comment: I am using http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videoreader.html VideoReader to read video file and in a while loop I read frames one by one which is chosen wrong according to time. Matlab 2014a/b is used. 

Also, it is acceptable to use fixedframerate video if there is a chance to obtain such configuration?